# Two different as_json methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I'd like to have my json render in two different ways. I now have my as_json method overridden to display a full object in json form like this:

```
{
    prop1: stuff,
    prop2: stuff,
    innerthings: {
        {
            prop1:stuff,
            prop2:stuff
        }
        {
            prop1:stuff,
            prop2:stuff
        }
    }
}
```

And the as_json looks like:

```
  #Renders json
  def as_json(options={})
    super(
        :except => [:created_at, :updated_at],
        :include => [{:innerthings = > {
                :except => [:created_at, :updated_at]
}}]

    )
  end
```

I'd also like to have a second option to render like this:

```
{
    prop1:stuff,
    prop2:stuff,
    countinnerthings:10
}
```

current when the code below is used, I get the first render:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: @thing}
end
```

I'd also like to be able to render with something like as_list that I could use in a case like the below to render just a simple list of the objects.

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render json: @things.as_list }
end
```

Is there a simple way to do this in ruby on rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just define an `as_list` method

```
def as_list
   {
    prop1: "stuff"
   }
end
```

If you need to use includes etc you can call `as_json` from your `at_list` method. As had been said serializers are a better option in general.

Comment: This works, but I had to modify my as json to do something like if options == nil || options.count == 0 basicjson else super(options) end

Answer (score 3):

Instead of rolling your own as_json method. Take a look at [ActiveModel Serializers](http://railscasts.com/episodes/409-active-model-serializers).  I think it will satisfy you use-case and help organize your code.

Comment: I've seen the ActiveModel Serializers and see their merit; however, this is a legacy system that was developed prior to my serializers understanding, and it currently isn't an option to migrate.